# How to load a view XIB as a subview into a view controller XIB

Tags: iphone, ios4, interface-builder, xib

I have a custom view I made with an IB file since it's quite complex: (RotatorView.xib/.h/.m).
I want to add the RotatorView as a subview to a view controller.  I can do this programmatically using:

```
NSArray *array = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"RotatorView" 
                                               owner:self options:nil];
```

But I'd rather not do that. It would be better for my design if I could add the RotatorView to the canvas of a View Controller in Interface Builder.  That way I could use IB to manage the properties of each instance of RotatorView instead of setting properties programmatically in each class.  Is there a way that I can add my custom view with XIB to a parent view controller?   Do I have to build an IB plugin to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a UIView control to the canvas in IB and change its class name to match your custom view class name.
Although this will save you from calling `loadNibNamed` method programmatically, but you'll not be able to set the custom properties directly from IB.

The only solution for doing this is to build an [IB plugin](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/IBPlugInGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html), but unfortunately it seems you can't make Cocoa Touch IB plugins because you can't make Cocoa Touch frameworks.

Comment: I did some more research and came to the same conclusion.  It seems like a strange omission though.  I can build a custom view with IB but I can't embed that custom view in another view controller XIB.